# Comparison between Hyper-V and PowerShell vShpere

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, powercli

May I know what is the comparison between these 2 softwares. Hyper-V and PowerShell vSphere. I know that Hyper-V is only used in Microsoft. And PowerShell vSphere can be used in most OS. But I wish to compare these two softwares in Microsoft OS.

Thanks.

Comment: "Powershell vSphere" appears to simply be a Powershell interface to VMware's vSphere.  Are you really trying to compare Microsoft Hyper-V to VMware vSphere?

Comment: @Fred Nurk So am I right to say, PowerShell scripting is done in VMware vSphere. Then how is PowerCLI related to PowerShell? PowerCLI does cmdlets? Yes am comparing Microsoft Hyper-V to VMware vSphere running on Microsoft Servers.

Comment: I do not quite get the link between PowerShell & VMware vSphere & PowerCLI. Which is a scripting language and which is a software using to run these scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vSphere PowerCLI, allows you to use PowerShell to communicate with the vSphere advanced programming interface (API).

PowerCLI 4.0 = VI Toolkit 1.5 + Bug Fixes + Host Profile Cmdlets

"Host Profile Cmdlets" Are commands that allow to create configuration files of ESX hosts and to apply to another host in order to evaluate differences.